# Installing Tk in Anaconda3

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, anaconda, tk-toolkit

I am attempting to use Tkinter with tkMessageBox and tkFileDialog in an anaconda3 installation on windows, but I can't figure out how to install it. Every solution seems to be to just use a completely separate stock python installation, but it seems like there has to be a way to install it in the anaconda3 directory without starting over completely and manually recreating the anaconda plugin setup or having multiple separate installs. I know variants of this question have been addressed before, but they've been unhelpful thus far in solving the problem.

Comment: you should have already installed but in Python 3 it is `tkinter` (lower "t") , `tkinter.filedialog.FileDialog`, `tkinter.messagebox.Message` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

Comment: So you're saying messagebox and filedialog don't have to be imported seperately?

Comment: Wrong. You have to do `import tkinter.filedialog` to use `tkinter.filedialog.FileDialog()` and `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()`. Or `from tkinter.filedialog import FileDialog, askopenfilename` to use `FileDialog()` and `askopenfilename()`. Similar `import tkinter.messagebox` to use `tkinter.messagebox.Message()` and `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo()`. Or `from tkinter.messagebox import Message, showinfo` to use `Message()` and `showinfo()`